# Check if text property is set to hidden

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking a way to check if in a Word document, the Text property of any text is set to Hidden or not.

I am using the following code but I think I am not doing in a right way.

```
Sub ToggleShowHiddenText()
    If ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True Then
        MsgBox "Yes Text is hidden"
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = False Then
        MsgBox "Text is not hidden"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: again, what do you wan to check? try `Font.Hidden` property of text

Comment: @mehow But I dont know how to do that. Can you please post a little example.

Comment: [google `Font.Hidden` + `Word VBA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835996(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: any programmer needs to learn how to find the resources needed to work with object models/libraries. They are usually called APIs. Word object model is well described on MSDN - all you need is to find the correct documentation and read it. There is no other way to become a programmer, at least not a very good one etc

Comment: @mehow Yes I did it now. Thanks for your comment. Its working now. Can I post the answer here or should I delete this post? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, thanks for @me how.

I go through word by word in the Active Document and then if Font.Properties are set to Hidden then show a Message Box.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ToggleShowHiddenText()


For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges

    For Each w In sentence.Words

       If w.Font.Hidden = True Then
        MsgBox w

        End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```